# What's the best way to insert HTML chunk via WordPress plugin function?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating WordPress plugin and I want to be able to provide an interface (to the programmer that installs the plugin) through some registered function in WP that when called in the template prints a HTML chunk inside the page.

What's the best way of doing it? I don't want to use echo to print large chunk of HTML from inside the function. The ideal would be having a .html file or .php file with the HTML code in it and my plugin function would simply load it when the function is called.

Does that make sense? Should I be using widgets API for this instead?

Thank you.

Comment: I ended up using `include` function to invoke the HTML chunk I wanted to render (from a separate file). That worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, which I use for an rss feed. if you remove the `is feed` conditional clause you should be able to just add content.

```
/*-----------*/
/* Add custom feed content footer
/*-----------*/

function add_feed_content($content) {

    if(is_feed()) {

        $content .= '<p>*This post was first published on...*</p>';
        $content .= '<footer><p>*Add some Content here*</p></footer>';
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'add_feed_content');
add_filter('the_content', 'add_feed_content');
```

You might also need to create an admin page with a form to store the content and retrieve it if it likely to change, or just hard-code it here if it is a one-off.

Comment: This satisfies the need where I explicitly call the function from specific part of the template and its returned value is printed inside the page? It's something the programmer will place a bit above the page footer.

Comment: Depends if you are adding content after posts or in a template? If you are editing a custom template file, just add your hank there.

Comment: I just want to change the template, like adding a HTML chunk before footer.